# Scraping next page XHR request

Tags: python, ajax, scrape

I want to scrape the second page of this user [reviews](https://www.tripadvisor.com/members/1happykat).

However the next button executes a XHR request, and while I can see it using Chrome developer tools, I cannot replicate it.

Comment: I managed to replicate it using Python and requests. It took me a while because I needed to set the security token which you get it right if the request to the first page of the user includes the cookie field. Once you get right the query to the first page, everything you need is available in the html of the page retrieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so easy task. First of all you should install this
[extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/request-maker/kajfghlhfkcocafkcjlajldicbikpgnp).
It helps you to test own requests based on captured data, i.e. catch and simulate requests with captured data.

As I see they send a token in this XHR request, so you need to get it in from html page body(stores in source code, js variable "taSecureToken" ).

Next you need to do four steps:

1. Catch POST request with plugin
2. Change token to saved before
3. Set `limit` and `offset` variables in POST request data
4. Generate request with resulted body

Note: on this request server returns json data(not the html with next page) containing info about loaded objects on next page.

Comment: Thanks g1zmo. I almost  figured it out. Just fyi, I need also to set the memberId (which for some reason is different from the user id) and it is embedded in the html of the first page.